# Minimalist crash reporting in an unsigned applet

Tags: java, exception, applet, crash-reports

What options do I have to do minimalist crash reporting in an unsigned applet?

I cannot use an `UncaughtExceptionHandler` because of permissions (I just tested), but at least I'd like to show something that the user can report to me. Pretty sure I cannot send an email, but at least showing a callstack would be nice. During beta testing, most exceptions are not fatal enough to prevent that.

- Would you put a `try`-`catch` at several strategic places?
- Any reasonable way to catch exceptions thrown on the `Event Dispatch Thread`?

Comment: *"What options do I have to do minimalist crash reporting in an unsigned applet?"*  Since an unsigned applet can 'phone home', an applet could make a report direct back to the server, without bothering the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would you put a try-catch at several strategic places?

Yes.  There are very few other options for a sand-boxed app.